# Bind dynamic @keyframes rule to Vue's `:style` property

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I've wanted to create a border animation when user is waiting for status update over websocket.

It's using working like this: once status is sent, I'm adding a loading class that uses css rule `animation: borderAnimation 2s infinite` and wanted to define keyframes for this animation dynamically, by binding to this element also `:style='myDynamicKeyframesDefinition'` which looks like this:

```
// this is a computed property
myDynamicKeyFramesDefinition () {
return `@keyframes borderAnimation {
  0% {border: 2px solid ${this.currentStatusColor}}
  50% {border: 2px solid ${this.nextStatusColor}}
  100% {border: 2px solid ${this.currentStatusColor}}}`
}
```

Reason why I'm using such approach is that I've got plenty status codes that user can toggle between so writing down all combinations would be probably highly ineffective (since these can change in the future so maintaining this would be even worse)
I'm not sure if it's even possible - any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Never saw @keyframes rules in inline-style's instead why dont you try with css transition-property: border-color; transition-duration: 400ms; transition-timing-function: ease-in-out; and change the border-color in inline-style as per your logic. as I see you are not trying to animate width and height of the border.

Comment: will try that out - thank you!